# Import other module properly in java-maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven project with two modules. Both of them have their own spring application, controller and mybatis interface as follows:

```
project
 |_ module1
    |_ src
       |_ com.project.module1
          |_ Person.java
          |_ Controller.java
          |_ Application.java
          |_ MybatisMapper.java
    |_ pom.xml // pom of module1
 |_ module2
    |_ src
       |_ com.project.module2
          |_ Student.java // import Person.java
          |_ Controller.java
          |_ Application.java
          |_ MybatisMapper.java
    |_ pom.xml // pom of module2
|_ pom.xml // pom of project
```

Since module2 is dependent on module1, so I add dependence in `pom.xml` of module2 as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I start my application of module2, error occurs:

> Parameter 1 of constructor in com.project.module2 required a bean of type 'com.project.module1.MybatisMapper' that could not be found.

It seems that module2 imports all components of module1 (maybe including the controller?), and fails to find mapper of module1 properly since I specify `@MapperScan("com.project.module2")`. 
How to import just `Person.java` in module2? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the `Application` class in module2 under the base parent package if you want to use all classes in module1, otherwise, you can use the `ComponentScan` annotation with `excludeFilters` to exclude not needed classes in module1:

```
package com.project;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project",
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.project\\.module1\\.Controller\\..*"),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.project\\.module1\\.MybatisMapper\\..*")
        })
public class Application  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

another option is to have a third module that contains only common classes between modules 1&2 and being imported in both.

Comment: Actually module 1 and 2 are somewhat independent. I just wanna reuse `Person.java`.

Comment: So you might need to move it to a separate module and being used in  both modules, or you change the packages and use the components scan annotation with filters https://www.baeldung.com/spring-componentscan-filter-type